# Taking photos with Flask displays slowly

Tags: python, opencv, flask

I'm trying to take photos with flask and opencv. The idea is that going to a URL `<flask-servers-ipaddress>:5000/take-photo` will take a photo and display it in the browser.

Unfortunately, the data is loading very slowly... my attempts at speeding it up have not worked.

[image]

## Simple Code

Run as a standard flask app (`flask run --host=0.0.0.0`). You can then load the photo on any local device by going to `<flask-server-ipaddress>:5000/take-photo`

```py
import cv2
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

# Setup camera
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 5)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

@app.route('/take-photo')
def take_photo():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    success, encoded_image = cv2.imencode('.png', frame)
    resp = flask.make_response(encoded_image.tobytes())
    resp.content_type = "image/jpeg"
    return resp
```

## Multiprocessing version

Here I tried to speed it up by reading frames in a separate process and passing them through a queue... it didn't work. In retrospect the slowdown is probably in flask since the image starts loading quickly but takes a long time to finish.

```py
import cv2
import flask
import time

from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

def camera_process(queue):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/dev/video0')
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 6)

    while True:
        # Read the frame
        ret, frame = cap.read() 

        # If the encoding was successful, put it in the queue and clear
        if ret:
            queue.put(frame)

        # Clear out any old frames
        if queue.qsize() > 1:
            queue.get()

        time.sleep(1/24)

queue = Queue(2)
process = Process(target=camera_process, args=(queue,))
process.start()

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

@app.route('/take-photo')
def take_photo():
    frame = queue.get()
    success, encoded_image = cv2.imencode('.png', frame)
    resp = flask.make_response(encoded_image.tobytes())
    resp.content_type = "image/jpeg"
    return resp
```

## System Notes

- Client computer is a recent laptop (gen11 i5, etc). `top` shows that most resources are free
- Flask server is a raspberry pi 4, 8GB RAM. Likewise, `top` shows most resources to be free (except when running the multiprocessing code with no `time.sleep`)

  - Camera is a USB webcam

Comment: I don't think multi-processing would be of much help here. Can you please let me know the value of `frame.shape` after `ret, frame = cap.read()` in your first code snippet ?

Comment: I'm afraid you're right... I had read somewhere that capturing in a separate thread/process could make displaying videos smoother, but here it doesn't seem to help. I don't think I use `frame.shape`?

Comment: From `frame.shape`, I am trying to infer the size of image you are dealing with, because images with larger width and height will slow down the `cv2.imencode('.png', frame)` method call. So it's a good idea to check for the dimension of images you are dealing with

Comment: Oops! My bad, they're 640x480

Comment: This doesn't seems much. What is the current latency of the end-point and what are your expectations ?

Comment: That's odd... pinging the server is 250ms even though we're on the same LAN

Comment: It looks like I might have stumbled on a common ubuntu problem that causes large network latency when ipv6 is enabled